# Type error with sklearn's accuracy_score function

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, typeerror, sparse-matrix

I am trying to run accuracy_score from sklearn.metrics in Python. My true y's and predicted y's are both in sparse matrix format --

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_true = sp.csr_matrix(y.values) # where y is a multi-label dataframe
y_pred = model.predict(X) # X is same format as y_true    
accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I checked the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)  and it should be able to accept sparse matrices.

Just for clarity, when I try to look at the contents, I get the following for both:

```
[In]  y_true
[Out] <9646x1248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
                 with 36700 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
[In]  y_pred
[Out] <9646x1248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
                 with 373603 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix my input?

Comment: How do you know the problem with the type of `y_true` or `y_pred`?  Based on what little information you give it could be somewhere else.  We need some or all of the error traceback to properly identify what object it's talking about.

Comment: With the example arrays from `accuracy_score` docs, `accuracy_score(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]]), np.ones((2, 2)))`, it works if they are converted to `csr`.  What is it about your matrices that makes them work when dense, but not when `csr`?

Comment: Apparently `accuracy_score` checks the type of the inputs, using `sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target`.  This error is produced when a sparse matrix fails the `sklearn.utils.multiclass.is_multilabel` test.  A dense array (`ndarray`) can satisfy other criteria.  I deduced this by looking at the traceback and associated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert matrices into regular matrix  `y_pred = y_pred.A` and `y_true = y_true.A`, then compute `accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)`